# I can't import sklearn modules anymore

Tags: python, scikit-learn, python-module

Previously sklearn worked without a hitch. Since yesterday however, I receive the error message
'cannot import name 'logger'' , when I try to import a sklearn module (originally RobustScaler, but it happens for all sklearn modules now.) [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7w7qq.jpg).

My sklearn version is 0.21.3 and I've tried to update the module (Requirements were already up-to-date) and to uninstall and then reinstall the module. This did not work either.

Your help would be appreciated!

Regards,
RM

EDIT: I solved it. I had to upgrade the joblib module (Through the command prompt). My former version was `joblib 0.12.5` and my new version is `joblib 0.13.2`. The update command was `pip install -U joblib`.

Comment: Do you have by any chance  created a file called `joblib.py`? Also check if there is a module called `joblib` in your `site-packages`

Comment: No `joblib.py` file, only a `joblib` folder. Is the `joblib` folder what you meant when you stated the `joblib` module?

Answer (score 0):

check if you use many environments. For example under Anaconda, you can create different env (ex. Python 3.7 or 2.6).

Comment: Hi Ghiz,
How do I check that?
RM

Comment: check this link if you work under anaconda [https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#viewing-a-list-of-your-environments]